# Dollar cents axis in Altair

Tags: python, altair

I would like to format the axis in the following plot such that it shows dollar cents instead of fractional dollars.

```py
data = pd.DataFrame({
    'x': np.random.rand(20)
})

alt.Chart(data).mark_tick().encode(
    alt.X('x', axis=alt.Axis(format='$.2f'))
)
```

Comment: Can you give an example of how you would like the output to be formatted?

Comment: "3.5¢", "5¢", etc.

Comment: Actually, what I really want is that to be GBP pence, so "3.5p", "5p", etc. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `labelExpr` to add arbitrary characters to the axis labels:

```
data = pd.DataFrame({
    'x': np.random.rand(20)
})

alt.Chart(data).mark_tick().encode(
    alt.X('x', axis=alt.Axis(labelExpr='datum.value + "p"'))
)
```

[image]